# Bash: reshape a dataset of many rows to dataset of many columns

Tags: bash, reshape

Suppose I have the following data:

```
# all the numbers are their own number.  I want to reshape exactly as below
0 a 
1 b
2 c
0 d
1 e
2 f
0 g
1 h
2 i
...
```

And I would like to reshape the data such that it is:

```
0 a d g ...
1 b e h ... 
2 c f i ...
```

Without writing a complex composition.  Is this possible using the unix/bash toolkit?

Yes, trivially I can do this inside a language.  The idea is **NOT TO** "just" do that.  So if some `cat X.csv | rs [magic options]` sort of solution (and `rs`, or the bash reshape command, would be great, except it isn't working here on debian stretch) exists, that is what I am looking for.

Otherwise, an equivalent answer that involves a composition of commands or script is out of scope: already got that, but would rather not have it.

Comment: `#` is stand in for one number alone? So you basically want to group by `0`, `1` and `2`?

Comment: @Inian no, any number whatsoever.  I will clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU `datamash`:

```
$ datamash -s -W -g 1 collapse 2 < file
0       a,d,g
1       b,e,h
2       c,f,i
```

Options:

- `-s` sort
- `-W` use whitespace (spaces or tabs) as delimiters
- `-g 1` group on the first field
- `collapse 2` print comma-separated list of values of the second field

To convert the tabs and commas to space characters, pipe the output to `tr`:

```
$ datamash -s -W -g 1 collapse 2 < file | tr '\t,' ' '
0 a d g
1 b e h
2 c f i
```

Comment: freaking awesome, thank you -- this datamash is something I have never even heard of.

Answer (score 0):

bash version:

```
function reshape {
    local index number key
    declare -A result
    while read index number; do
        result[$index]+=" $number"
    done
    for key in "${!result[@]}"; do
        echo "$key${result[$key]}"
    done
}
reshape < input
```

We just need to make sure input is in unix format